# are there two meaning?

Tags: ambiguity

> Other studies, including in the United States, have shown this same
>   pattern, with girls who begin developing earlier than their peers
>   vulnerable to depression in adolescence.

Without context, are there two meaning? :

1. Girls are vulnerable to depression in adolescence.
2. Peers are vulnerable to depression in adolescence.

Put another way: if sentence is

> There are girls who begin developing earlier than their peers vulnerable to depression in adolescence.

then is there ambiguity which group is vulnerable to depression in adolescence?